Using Kraft with SASL_SSL
i'm Having a lot of issues to make this work, here is my files
server1.properties


############################# Server Basics #############################
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=1
controller.quorum.voters=1@ip:19092,2@ip:19093,3@ip:19094

listeners=BROKER://ip:9092,CONTROLLER://ip:19092,SASL_SSL://ip:9095
advertised.listeners=BROKER://ip:9092,SASL_SSL://ip:9095
listener.security.protocol.map=BROKER:SASL_PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL


inter.broker.listener.name=BROKER
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER

ssl.truststore.location=/etc/pki/root/host.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=removed
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/pki/root/host.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=removed
ssl.key.password=removed

sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
sasl.mechanism.controller.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN

listener.name.broker.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
    username="removed" \
    password="removed" \
    user_admin="removed";

listener.name.controller.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
    username="removed" \
    password="removed" \
    user_admin="removed";


# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/server1/kraft-combined-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1


############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=1

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

server2.properties and server3.properties are copies of the server1.properties, just changing the node.id and ports
client.properties
bootstrap.servers=ip:9092
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/pki/root/host.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=removed
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/pki/root/host.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=removed
ssl.key.password=removed


kafka.log seems to start just fine and no problems on it, but when i try to create a topic with the command:
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test --bootstrap-server ip:9092 --command-config /opt/kafka/config/kraft/SSL/client.properties

the problem is showed as :
WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/ip:9092) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

if I use the port 9095 it gave this:
WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/ip:9095) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) 

With SASL_Plaintext it works fine, also for just Plaintext

To rule out network or client certificate issues, do the commands work on the brokers themselves?

@OneCricketeer, interbroker communication works fine, no errors showed on the log

I meant the topic creation command. That's ran locally from the broker, or a different system?

@OneCricketeer is running locally
